# How can I write a generic method in Rust that can accept any value that can be converted into another?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to be able to receive a path-like value in a generic function. The idea would be that I want to be able to receive anything that could be converted into PathBuf, like this:

```rust
fn build<P>(path: P) -> Some<Handler>{
  let mut base_path = PathBuf::from(path);

  ...
}
```

But, of course, this doesn't work without the proper trait. Yet I'm unable to figure out how to write the generic trait stating that I want to accept a value that can be accepted as `from` for another type. Like this (which of course doesn't work):

```rust
fn build<P>(path: P) -> Some<Handler>
  where P: PathBuf::from::<P>
{
  let mut base_path = PathBuf::from(path);

  ...
}
```

Comment: `P: Into<PathBuf>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper trait for cases where you want "anything that converts to" is `Into`.

However, the idiomatic trait for accepting paths in particular is `AsRef<Path>`. This is how the standard library functions taking a path do it.

```
fn build<P>(path: P) where P: AsRef<Path>
```

or the shorter form:

```
fn build<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P)
```

or even shorter:

```
fn build(path: impl AsRef<Path>)
```

If your function is not trivial, you should immediately forward to a non-generic function:

```
fn build(path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
  build_impl(path.as_ref())
}
fn build_impl(path: &Path) { .... }
```

And if you need a `PathBuf`, you simply call `to_owned()` on the `Path`.

For reference, you use the same technique with `Into`:

```
fn build(p: impl Into<PathBuf>) { build_impl(p.into()) }
fn build_impl(p: PathBuf) {}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with the `Into` implementation, as I ultimately convert into a `PathBuf`. Thanks for elaborating on the idiomatic way of receiving `Path`s, I was also wondering how that worked.

Comment: You should take `impl AsRef<Path>`, not `&impl AsRef<Path>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I disagree. There's no reason why I would ever want to take ownership of any argument here.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It's more convenient when you have a `PathBuf` or `String` you don't need anymore. And anyway, [this is what the standard library does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.remove_dir.html) so I will argue it is more idiomatic.